# How does Vue use this.$route.query in a JS file

Tags: vuejs2

I want to use this.$route.query in the JS file ,but `this` point `undefined`

```js
console.log(this, "query"); //undefined
console.log(this.$route.query); //error
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a global variable for it.
In your component:

```
mounted() {
    window.$route = this.$route
}
```

Then you can access it from anywhere as `window.$route.query`.
If you need to make it reactive, just create a watcher for `$route` and update your global variable in it.